# Hide DLC weapons from the in-game store

Tags: killing-floor

Getting in and out of a shop quickly can be a big thing in Killing Floor. Golden weapons and other cosmetic detritus take up valuable space in the trading screen, meaning I have to spend a little more time looking for the weapon I want to buy. Can these weapons be hidden to speed up my shopping?

Comment: KF player for years here. As far as I know, you can't.